# Javascript how to get value and key seperately from Array Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JS array in this format and I want to get all keys in different variables, and values in different variable. This is my code. I am trying to get keys and values in different variables.

```
<script>
    var testVar = [ {ANUMBER: "new message"}, {ANUMBER: "new message number"},  {ANUMBER: "new message email "},{AMDL: "new message"}];

    for (var labelkey in testVar){
        if (errorsarr.hasOwnProperty(labelkey)) {
            var val = errorsarr[labelkey];
            //console.log(val);
            console.log(labelkey);    
        }           
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in diff"? You have no variable called `diff`

Comment: Where is `errorsarr` variable in your code?

Comment: means i want to get key and value seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function, you get an array of `key`, `value` pairs that you can loop over with a `for ... of` loop.

```js
var testVar = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third"}

        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(testVar)){
          console.log(key, value)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need two loops to access each key of your array object because your `testVar` is an array. First loop iterate over your array and second loop will iterate over object.

```js
var testVar = [ {ANUMBER: "new message"}, {ANUMBER: "new message number"},  {ANUMBER: "new message email "},{ANUMBER: "new message"}];
JSON.stringify(testVar);
for( labelkey in testVar){
   var value= testVar[labelkey];
   for( key in value ){
      console.log("Key="+key, "and value="+value[key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: yes it's working but my last key is diff. Is it possible to merge/add all values of "ANUMBER" key under it and all values of another key "AMDL" under it?

Comment: @testingusers2019 can you add a sample of key `diff`. How it looks like i.e what is end result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element and get the key and value of each object using `Object.entries`.

```js
var testVar = [{ 1: "new message" }, { 2: "new message number" }, { 3: "new message email " }, { 4: "new message" }];
var keys = [];
var values = [];
testVar.forEach(e => {
 var [key, value] = Object.entries(e)[0];
 keys.push(key) && values.push(value)
});
console.log(keys)
console.log(values)
```

OR

```js
var testVar = [{ 1: "new message" }, { 2: "new message number" }, { 3: "new message email " }, { 4: "new message" }];
var keys =  testVar.map(e =>  Object.entries(e)[0][0]);
var values = testVar.map(e =>  Object.entries(e)[0][1]);
console.log(keys)
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testVar = [ {ANUMBER: "new message"}, {ANUMBER: "new message number"},  {ANUMBER: "new message email "},{AMDL: "new message"}];

ANUMBER_VALUE = [];
AMDL_VALUE = [];

for(var testvar of testVar){
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(testvar)){

        console.log("key: "+key)
        console.log("value: "+value)

        if(key == "ANUMBER"){
          ANUMBER_VALUE.push(value);
        }
        else{
          AMDL_VALUE.push(value);
        }
    }
}
console.log("ANUMBER_VALUE: "+ ANUMBER_VALUE)
console.log("AMDL_VALUE: "+ AMDL_VALUE)
```

Comment: it's working but my last key is diff. Is it possible to merge/add all values of "ANUMBER" key under it and all values of another key "AMDL" under it?

Comment: yes it returns output according to my requirment but it's not dynamic means there can be more keys so should i difine array variable for each keys?